# Is there ever a reason to use triple-slash reference directive in TypeScript 3.x+ if you are using ES6+?

Tags: javascript, typescript, import, typescript-typings

If you have `target` set to `ES6` or later using `typescript` is there ever a point in using the triple slash `reference` directive instead of `ES6` `import` keyword?

Is the reason that typing types authors use the `reference` directive because they still need to support non-`ES6` imports?